# Custom PowerShell tab-completion for a specific command?

Tags: powershell, tab-completion

I was wondering if it's possible to create a custom tab completion in PowerShell, that would provide a specific list of arguments after a certain command?

When launching Visual Studio from a command line, you can type `devenv /rootsuffix HiveName` to have Visual Studio launch a new "hive" with that name, creating a folder called `HiveName` on the disk in a special location.

I want to be able to type in PowerShell: `devenv /rootsuffix [tab]`, and get a list of existing hives (from looking up in a directory/registry, doesn't matter), overriding the default behavior, which is filename completion.

Is doing something like this possible?

Comment: [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/26/the-new-tabexpansion-feature.aspx) is "oldish", so there might be better ways in newer PS versions.

Comment: @Christian.K cool! Running `$function:tabexpansion > c:\temp\tabexpansion.ps1` revealed that I have an (excellent) extension installed called [Jump-Location](https://github.com/tkellogg/Jump-Location) that does just that! That's a great starting point, thank you!

Comment: Which PowerShell version you use?

Comment: you should have a look at [tabexpansion++](https://github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus)

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using the [`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter) command.

The following is an example of code that uses the command (which can be copied and pasted into your PowerShell window):

```
# Function that will be registered with the command
function Cmd {
    Param(
        [string] $Param
    )

    Write-Host "Param: $param"
} 

# The code that will perform the auto-completion
$scriptBlock = {
    # The parameters passed into the script block by the
    #  Register-ArgumentCompleter command
    param(
        $commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete,
        $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameters
    )

    # The list of values that the typed text is compared to
    $values = 'abc','adf','ghi'

    foreach ($val in $values) {
        # What has been typed matches the value from the list
        if ($val -like "$wordToComplete*") {
            # Print the value
            $val
        }
    }
}

# Register our function and auto-completion code with the command
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName Cmd `
 -ParameterName Param -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

We can check that this code works properly by typing the following incomplete commands into the shell and pressing the `TAB` key (where `<PRESS TAB>` is typed) in the prompt:

```
# Using autocomplete with the TAB key will produce the results: abc, adf
PS > Cmd -Param a<PRESS TAB>

# Using autocomplete with the TAB key will produce the results: abc
PS > Cmd -Param ab<PRESS TAB>
```